# InvalidOperationException: ReadName can only be called when State is Name, not when State is EndOfDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I get that exception when using MongoDB.Driver Version="2.19.0". The code is (Configuration being a subdocument):

```
return await _customerCollection.Find(x => x.CustomerId == id).Project(x => x.Configuration).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

On Version 2.18 it just returns null. Is this a bug in the Mongo C# driver?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this appears to be fixed in 2.19.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Comment: I experienced the same exception. Updating the driver solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown only for Customer documents that don't have a Configuration. Still, since it didn't happen in 2.18 I suppose this is a MongoDB.Driver bug introduced in 2.19.

At the moment I changed the code to:

```
var customer = await _customerCollection.Find(x => x.CustomerId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 
return customer?.Configuration;
```